# Am I getting Java and JavaScript (ECMA-262) mixed up?

Tags: java, methods, casting, graphics2d

I'm new to Java and JavaScript.  While working though some Java Tutorials, I got to the part about casting:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
```

Is the component method `paint` casting a `Graphics` object `g` onto an `Object` class `{}` or am I getting this idea mixed up with JavaScript where a function is an Object?

```
function Graphics() {this.type = 'graphics object'};
var g = new Graphics();
g.type;
//"graphics object"
Graphics.prototype.g2d = 'g2d object';
g.type;
//"graphics object"
g.g2d;
//"g2d object"
```

When `paint(g)` is called, is it adding `Graphics` attributes to `{}` and then adding `Graphics2D` attributes to `Graphics`?

EDIT:  From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/rendering.html)

> To employ Java 2D API features in the application, cast the Graphics object passed into a component’s rendering method to a Graphics2D object.

When is says cast `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` is `g` changing by adding extra attributes and then referring to it thereafter as `g2`?

Comment: Your question is not that clear.

Comment: java =/= javascript. They are two completely different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referencing about JavaScript but the first code segment is casting a `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D` object.

The object is not changing. Java, unlike JavaScript is strongly typed. So g was a `Graphics2D` object the whole time. Casting just lets the compiler know that it is one.

Also, you can't add attributes to functions in Java.

Comment: Is casting similar to the prototype chain, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Kind of, but inheritance in Java is very different from JavaScript. You are on the right track though - `Graphics2D` is-a `Graphics` object which in a very, very general way is like a prototype chain.